# DB2 SQL better way to get count of unique values based on ID than SUM+CASE

Tags: sql, performance, db2

I am able to count the occurrences of unique values per ID in the same record, but it seems there must be a more efficient way? Something like `COUNT([Value],'2')`?

Here's a simple example

```
ID | Value
 1      2
 1      3
 1      3
 1      2
 2      2
 2      3
 2      3
 3      3
```

And this is my current code:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(CASE WHEN Value = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "COUNT2", 
SUM(CASE WHEN Value = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "COUNT3"
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

The results are:

```
ID | Count2 | Count3
 1      2        3
 2      1        2
 3      0        1
```

Is there a better way to get the count of unique values?

Comment: This method is fine.

Comment: Better in what way?  If you want the output "pivoted" as in your example, then your code is just about the best solution. I guess you could hide the `CASE` in a UDF, but short of writing your own user defined aggregate function, you would still need the `SUM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select distinct Id, Count2, Count3
from Table 
Outer Apply (select count(id) as Count2 from table t 
             where t.id = Table.id and value = 2) c2
Outer Apply (select count(id) as Count3 from table t 
             where t.id = Table.id and value = 3) c3
Order by Id asc
```

Typed from my phone so may need to be tweaked a little but something like this should work

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DECODE` if by "better" you mean more terse

```
WITH I (ID, V) AS (VALUES 
  (1,2)
, (1,3)
, (1,3)
, (1,2)
, (2,2)
, (2,3)
, (2,3)
, (3,3)
)
SELECT
    ID
,   COUNT(DECODE(V,2,1)) AS "Count2"
,   COUNT(DECODE(V,3,1)) AS "Count3"
FROM I
GROUP BY
    ID
```

returns

```
 ID Count2 Count3
 -- ------ ------
  1      2      2
  2      1      2
  3      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Db2 LUW 11.1.1.1 onward, you could take advantage of the fact that you can `SUM` `BOOLEAN` values.

```
WITH I (ID, V) AS (VALUES 
  (1,2)
, (1,3)
, (1,3)
, (1,2)
, (2,2)
, (2,3)
, (2,3)
, (3,3)
)
SELECT
    ID
,   SUM(V=2) AS "Count2"
,   SUM(V=3) AS "Count3"
FROM I
GROUP BY
    ID
```